# unable to connect to Azure DevOps Server from VS 2019

Tags: azure-devops, visual-studio-2019

I just installed Azure Devops 2019 on my server. I can access the devops server fine through the web portal but when I try to connect using VS 2019 - team explorer - manage connections - Add Azure Devops Server I get a error "TF400324: Azure DevOps Service are not available from server http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8080/tfs."

I also see that VS add :8080/tfs to the IP I add. But thats not the correct adress. When using Team Foundation Server this adress was valid but Azure Devops does not use the same.

So how can I connect to the new Azure DevOps server from VS 2019?

Comment: Probably you have done this, but have you tried to review the official documentation? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/projects/connect-to-projects?view=azure-devops&tabs=visual-studio-2019

Comment: Hi MTplus, is there any update for this issue? Please feel free to let me know if the issue persists to block you:)

Comment: Hi Lance, Sorry but no positive update. I had to rollback to my old setup which used TFS in order to get it to work. I simply didnt have time to mess around with this anymore. Sorry...

Comment: You're welcome. If you again meet that issue, feel free to let me know:)

Answer (score 7):

> So how can I connect to the new Azure DevOps server from VS 2019?

You can try:

1.Close all VS instances and then clean VS cache(`%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\16.xxx\ComponentModelCache`) and TFS cache(`%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Team Foundation\xx\Cache`).

2.Go to Control Panel -> User Accounts -> Manage your Credential -> Windows Credential, select the VSTS url to remove it.

[image]

3.Restart VS to re-connect to Devops server.

**In addition:**

1.Make sure you enter the correct URL. In VS if I don't enter correct URL of tfs instance, I would get this error:

[image]

2.Many factors can cause `TF400324`, just like above. So it could be better if you can share more details about your `TF400324`, `remote name not resolve`,`Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel` or what.

Comment: cleaning cache worked for me, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had issues connecting to DevOps.   I was using https and http.   The trick for me was to "Change Public URL" in the "Azure DevOps Server Administration Console".  This was done on the "Application Tier".    Once I had this done the redirect for HTTPS worked because it used a fully qualified DNS name that matched the certificate I was using.

If you are not using HTTPS,  then you may just have a DNS server issue.  Check the DNS settings on the client PC and use something like ping or nslookup to see if the server name resolves to the correct IP address.